# Qt Stylesheets and the "one argument" issue

Tags: c++, css, qt, user-interface, qtgui

I usually find a workaround for this, however it is getting on my nerves lately and I cannot find any information regarding it anywhere on the internet.

Right, I want to change the property of a progress bar I have in Qt and have set the initial values in the form designer.

This is what I have in my initial (and working) style sheet configuration:

```
QProgressBar {
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

QProgressBar::chunk {
    background-color: #05B8CC;
    width: 20px;
}
```

(NOTE: Bare in mind that I have done it in the Form Designer, which is the inbuilt drag and drop graphical designer for Qt)

However, I want to change it programmatically within the code by doing this:

```
ui->progressBar->styleSheet("QProgressBar::chunk { background-color: #05B8CC; width: 20px;}");
```

According to the [documentation for style sheets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html), it should be working with not problem whatsoever, but I get the following non-nonsensical error:

```
D:\Qt Projects\test\mainwindow.cpp:165: error: C2660: 'QWidget::styleSheet' : function does not take 1 arguments
```

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: It's a simple typo: you wrote `styleSheet` where you meant `setStyleSheet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are looking for is setStyleSheet